# Text missing in Question/Answer

Tags: bug, android-app

In the android app (1.0.58) I have been running into questions where there is no text in the question and or answers. On some questions it is just the answers where nothing is shown on other questions it is both the question and the answer. When the text does not show I can still see comments that have been posted to the question and answers. I have not been able to determine a pattern about which questions this happens to but the latest example would be [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/how-to-prevent-a-psychologically-fragile-person-from-harming-a-team) which I was not able to see the text for the question or answer.

I am using a Galaxy S3 with android 4.4.2 and the app is 1.0.58

I am unable to provide a screen shot for this problem

Also I don't feel this should be a duplicate of [android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-answer-body-multiple-sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-answer-body-multiple-sites) as that is not only from a earlier version of the app (posted almost a year ago), has no answer or solution and also appears to have no developer response at all.

Comment: What device and Android version are you using?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I have updated the question with my phone and android version.

Comment: For what it's worth I am seeing it too. Motorola Moto X (2013) Android 4.4.4. I can provide screen shots if needed.

Comment: I see this was fixed in the latest release1.0.59