# Posts not loading/rendering

Tags: bug, android-app

Lately the Stack Exchange android app (v 1.0.58 on an android 4.4 phone and a 5.0 tablet) won't render some posts. Both questions and answers are affected. I can see votes and comments but the post content is an empty white box.

[For example](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/4522/64):

> [image]

Comment: Not all posts are affected, but if you need a specific post that won't render, look no further than this one. I see no content in the box that should contain my question text. No picture either. I do see tags, votes, the bar with favorite, edit, share and the info below that.

Comment: Can you please link to the question/answer you posted?

Comment: ...Look no further than *which* one?

Comment: @Shog9 the post these comments are attached to. One example among many for me unfortunately.

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/4522/64

Comment: Lots of MathJax there, so all posts with MathJax are empty in the app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do see the problem a lot on posts with mathjax but I also have seen it on sites that don't even have mathjax enabled.

Comment: Hmm... looks like same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-answer-body-multiple-sites) then, which is still not fixed. @Shog you think it's the same issue too? (no android app for me, so can't really know)

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1188864/221519 does render for me with mathjax.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that bug you linked doesn't render :)

Comment: LOL, how ironic!

Comment: Can't reproduce; does this happen *consistently* for you? On which device (not just android version) - and which network?

Comment: @shog9 moto X (2013), stock android 4.4  and nexus 7 (flo) stock android 5.0. The phone is ATT and the WiFi exits my LAN over charter cable.

Comment: @Shog9 Consistent on the phone, less so on the tablet. Some posts that don't render initially start to render normally later. I can now see this question but could not until 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is a daily issue for me as well on my HTC Desire 816 with Android 4.4.2 and app version 1.0.58. Most posts render normally, but approximately one out of fifteen are blank.

The only commonality I have been able to identify is that the unrendered posts tend to be long--I have not yet seen a short post that exhibits the issue.

I can click "edit" to view the markdown of the affected questions and answers; so far, the problem only seems to appear on the rendered version.

The issue manifests on multiple sites: StackOverflow, Programmers, English and others. It affects both questions and answers, but not necessarily at the same time. I see blank questions with normal answers, and vice-versa.

Closing and reloading the application does not change the situation. I have installed the latest updates.

FWIW, this question renders as expected for me, but the one linked by Shadow Wizard in the comments above does not.

Examples of questions that exhibit this behavior on my device:

- [bootstrap responsive two column issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29055756/749181) (Question only--answers are displayed correctly)
- [Android app intermittently shows blank body in questions and answers (multiple sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231354/165786) (Question only)
- [php shopping cart -group by selection and get the total](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29052118/749181) (Question only)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288044/749181 (Answer only)
- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/17475/407 (Answer)