# Android-app renders posts with huge vertical gaps

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

This is not a duplicate of [Some posts are vertically scrollable on Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249697/some-posts-are-vertically-scrollable-on-android-app) or [Android app intermittently shows blank body in questions and answers (multiple sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s), because there the post is not readable at all.

What I experience now is that the post is complete but with a huge blank gap in between.

[image: top part of a post]  [image: bottom part of the same post]

Both screenshots show the same post, I have to scroll at least one whole screen between them, refreshing the view will sometimes help, sometimes a third refresh will bring the gap back.

The post in this example is [What to do when you can’t protect mobile app secret keys?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100129/what-to-do-when-you-can-t-protect-mobile-app-secret-keys)

I am using 1.0.73 on a S3-mini (GT-I8190), Cyanogenmod 11.

Comment: Thanks for this report! The same thing has been happening to me since I installed version 1.0.73 on my Samsung Galaxy S4, Android version 4.1.2.  It happens intermittently, and is not question-specific. Like you, I've found that a few refreshes will sometimes correct the problem. Switching to a different question or site helps also, but not every time.