# Questions page content display bug

Tags: bug, android-app

When I want to watch a question the content disappear.

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G920F
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (G920FXXU3DPCM)

Comment: Might be the return of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s).

Comment: @Portal Seems like its the rtl bug indeed. When i change my android language to english (ltr display) its sorted out. Cant i change only the stack app to display on ltr mode?

Comment: Yeah, i can confirm that after the last update the app is forced to display in LTR hence there's no bug in the view

Comment: @Disney how can i duplicate a future question? I think you wanted to mark the other question as duplicate? ☺