# GUI Presented badly

Tags: bug, android-app

When I look at a post I see a lot of blank areas.

> [image: White space image]

---

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: ONE A2003
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (31)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s

Comment: @Mithrandir no, different bug. Based on OP's name, good chance he's using an RTL layout as well.