# Blank questions and answers

Tags: bug, android-app

I have white blank on the posts.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Meizu
- Device Model: m2

  - OS Version: 5.1 (1464689330)

I can't see the questions and the answers and the comments. 
I saw that it's a common issue.. 
Does it have a fix?

**EDIT -** 
I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-body-in-questions-and-answers-multiple-s) answer. This answer is ~2 years old. It says that it will fix in the next update. 
His version is 1.0.59 - mine is 1.0.89. Huge different.

The problem is still exists!

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Why did you remove the correct [tag:android-app] tag and put a wrong tag instead??

Comment: @ShadowWizard I posted it through my smartphone (chrome) it suddenly it said that I can't add some of the tags.. I don't remember the exact error. anyway, thanks for adding!. pls see the edit about the duplicate question

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that. so the bug has returned, it happens. Voted to reopen this.

Comment: @qwer mine It's newer version. and It didn't answered there...

Comment: @DvirNaim for bug report, it doesn't matter if it's newer or older or not answered yet, as long as it's the same bug. (in short, SE app doesn't really support RtL layout yet)

Comment: @qwer if the primary language of myphone is defined to RTL language, is there a way to defined the SE app to be LTR instead of phone's RTL?

Comment: You could try searching that on [android.se]: [1](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29124/44325), [2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/78899/44325), [3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16827/44325), [4](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30414/44325). Seems the device needs to be rooted in general.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­